# Offset in Vertical Alignment of Legend Text and Symbol (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot some data and include linear trends. I wanted the legend to include the function of the trend but somehow the legend always shows a weird vertical offset of the symbol relative to the text (see Screenshot marked with light blue). Does anybody know why and could maybe also include a fix?

Thank you!

```py
l_y1_1 = ax.plot(x, y1, 'ro', label='Lithium', markersize=10)
l_y1_2 = ax.plot(x_extrapolate, y1_extrapolate,'r:', label = "%s" % poly1)

l_y2_1 = ax.plot(x, y2, 'bx', label='Chlor', markersize=10)
l_y2_2 = ax.plot(x_extrapolate, y2_extrapolate,'b:', label = "%s" % poly2)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
l_y3_1 = ax2.plot(x, y3, 'gD', label='Fluor', markersize=10)
l_y3_2 = ax2.plot(x_extrapolate, y3_extrapolate,'g:',label = "%s" % poly3)

l_y_tot = l_y1_1 + l_y1_2 + l_y2_1 + l_y2_2 + l_y3_1 + l_y3_2
y_labs = [l.get_label() for l in l_y_tot]
legend = ax.legend(l_y_tot, y_labs, loc = 'upper left')
```

[image: See Blue Markings]

Comment: Can you separate the markers and lines into two separate legends, and then merge them into one legend using the ax.add_artist.

# Create separate legends for markers and lines
legend1 = ax.legend(l_y1_1 + l_y2_1 + l_y3_1, y_labs[:3], loc='upper left', numpoints=1)
legend2 = ax.legend(l_y1_2 + l_y2_2 + l_y3_2, y_labs[3:], loc='upper left', ncol=2, handlelength=0)

# Add the line legend to the marker legend
ax.add_artist(legend2)

Comment: Possibly your `poly1`, `poly2` and `poly3` strings start with a newline character. You might want to remove that. Also, if they are strings, you can directly set `label=poly1` instead of `label = "%s" % poly1`. By the way, if you create your legend as `ax.legend(handles=l_y_tot, loc='upper left')`, you can leave out creating the `y_lbas` array.